# Displaying icons and texts on the grouped columns with Angular JS (ng-grid)

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I want to get the **ng-grid** supports for **icon** columns and **text** at the same time.

In my example, the first grouping column is an icon and the second a string.

I'm using the **gridOptions** property **aggregateTemplate**.

My goal is to display the grouped columns of icons and text correctly.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/A28EfoMRZP4YJTqXJRnq?p=preview) is my plnkr link.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'myData',
  groups: ['complexIcon.path', 'complex'],
  groupsCollapsedByDefault: false,
  enableSorting: true,
  sortInfo: { fields: [], columns: [], directions: [] },
  useExternalSorting: true,
  columnDefs: [{
      field: 'complexIcon.path',
      visible: false
  }, {
      field: 'complexIcon.situation',
      displayName: 'Situation'
  }, {
      field: 'complex',
      displayName: 'Date'
  }],
  aggregateTemplate: aggregateRowTemplate()
};

function aggregateRowTemplate() {
    var result = '';

    result = "<div ng-model=\"showIcon\" ng-init=\"showIcon={{showIconFunc(row)}}\" ng-click=\"row.toggleExpand()\" ng-style=\"rowStyle(row)\" class=\"ngAggregate\">";
    result += "<span ng-if=\"!showIcon\" style=\"display: inline\"><img ng-src=\"{{row.label}}\" lazy-src> ({{row.totalChildren()}})</span>\r";
    result += "<span ng-if=\"showIcon\" class=\"ngAggregateText\">{{row.label CUSTOM_FILTERS}} ({{row.totalChildren()}})</span>\r";
    result += "<div class=\"{{row.aggClass()}}\"></div></div>"

    return result;
}
```

My controller:

```
$scope.showIconFunc = function (row) {
  if (row.field == "complexIcon.path") {
      return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

How can I get the **ng-grid** supports for **icon** columns and **text** at the same time?

Thanks!